# Django print labels

Tags: django, python-2.7, ms-word, label

I have a database full of families with addresses. I want to print out mailing labels for each family. I have various avery labels to use, is there an easy way to do this task? Is there a library or some tutorials you know of that others have used to accomplish this?

I used a project that was ported to python 2.6 and used pyPDF to make a pdf with labels of specific dimensions, but I think it may be outdated. The labels printed don't line up. Do I just need to adjust these or is there an easier way to save the data and do a mail merge in Word?

If there is not another way, I guess I'll just create a spreadsheet with the fields to import into Word.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain so I can improve the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I did vote to close. This question is (a) asking us to find or recommend off-site resources, (b) extremely broad, (c) somewhat unclear (what does your "project that was ported to python 2.6 and used pyPDF" have to do with anything?), and (d) doesn't include any relevant code. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and [ask] for tips on asking good questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if anybody will find this helpful. I had an extremely tough time finding a way to print out mailing labels from my Django app.

Instead I decided to export an spreadsheet using the `xlwt` library. Then you can use MS Word's Mail Merge functions to get Avery labels for each of your contacts.